# Append Lines to Remote File using PHP

Tags: php

How you doing guys?
Recently, I've faced an issue while trying to overwrite new lines to remote file using PHP with help of FTP server ..

I had this function:

```
function addmgusertoConfig($cfgdata)
{
$dateadd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+0 days"));
$handle = fopen($cfgdata,'a');
fwrite($handle, 'MG: '.$_POST["user11"].' '.$_POST["pass11"].' # 
'.$_POST["skype"].' '.$_POST["host"].' '.$dateadd." # \n");
fclose($handle);
}
```

while:

```
$cfgdata="ftp://USER:PASSWORD@REMOTEHOST/SOMEDIR/THEFILE.txt";
```

When I post my data via php I get this error Logs :

```
[05-May-2018 07:33:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  
file_get_contents(ftp://...@remotehost/somedir/thefile.txt): failed to open 
stream: operation failed in /home/LOCALUSER/public_html/post_page.php on 
line 204
[05-May-2018 07:33:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  
fopen(ftp://...@remotehost/somedir/thefile.txt): failed to open stream: 
operation failed in /home/LOCALUSER/public_html/functions.php on line 202
[05-May-2018 07:33:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be 
resource, boolean given in /home/LOCALUSER/public_html/functions.php on 
line 203
[05-May-2018 07:33:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be 
resource, boolean given in /home/LOCALUSER/public_html/functions.php on line 
204
[05-May-2018 07:33:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  
fopen(ftp://...@remotehost/somedir/thefile.txt): failed to open stream: 
operation failed in /home/LOCALUSER/public_html/functions.php on line 192
[05-May-2018 07:33:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be 
resource, boolean given in /home/LOCALUSER/public_html/functions.php on line 
193
[05-May-2018 07:33:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be 
resource, boolean given in /home/LOCALUSER/public_html/functions.php on line 
194
```

Any Ideas how to fix this using the given function or any better function ?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: What happens if you call the URL in your Browser?

Comment: The file you are trying to read does not exists. So the resource does not get created. Then everything fails. The path to the file will be different than what you see in your browser. Also ftp is not a safe protocol. Your password is just hashed and everything is sent in the clear. Should be looking into the sftp.

Comment: @stickybit Nothing happens with I write in the URL in browser.. just a blank white page.

Comment: @JasonK If FTP isn't secure, please suggest any fix for my code to use even fopen fwrite or sftp connection method..

Comment: Is the file supposed to be empty?

Comment: @stickybit No .. the file had many things inside.. and each time I post remotely, the data should be appended within the file as new line

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759575/cannot-write-a-file-to-aws-ec2-instance-php/49760437#49760437

Comment: Then the error is somewhere there. May be it's not the right URL. Or the FTP server doesn't work properly.

Comment: @stickybit The FTP server is working fine.. When I try to connect to the FTP using any FTP Client such as FileZilla it connects with all Ok .. I am using Ubuntu server with vsftpd ..