# Could not create file Using PHP code

Tags: php

On the 000webhost.com server

This is the code

```
<?php
$my_file = fopen("my_test.txt", 'w');

fclose($my_file );
```

I thank those who help me in advance

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759575/cannot-write-a-file-to-aws-ec2-instance-php/49760437#49760437

Comment: Excellent
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the function chmod
https://www.php.net/function.chmod

```
$file = "my_test.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
chmod($file, 0777);
```

Note* fwrite is optional in your case if you need to enter some data in file